# Making the labels of the scatterplot vertical and horizontal in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using `Pandas` to draw a scatterplot matrix: `from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix`. The problem is that the names of the columns in the `DataFrame` are too long and I need them to be vertical in the x-axis and horizontal in the y-axis so they can fit. I'm not able to figure out at all how to do that in Pandas. I know how to do it in `matplotlib` but not in Pandas.

My code:

```
pylab.clf()
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=the_labels)
axs = scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, diagonal='kde')
```

Edit:
I need to use `pylab.clf()` because I'm plotting a lot of figures, so calling `pylab.figure()` each time is too memory consuming.

Comment: Do you want the column names to be rotated or ticks.

Answer (score 17):

Major help from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18994338/2632856

```
a = [[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4, 5], [1, 6], [2,7], [1,8]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['askdabndksbdkl','aooweoiowiaaiwi'])
axs = pd.scatter_matrix( df, alpha=0.2, diagonal='kde')
n = len(df.columns)
for x in range(n):
    for y in range(n):
        # to get the axis of subplots
        ax = axs[x, y]
        # to make x axis name vertical  
        ax.xaxis.label.set_rotation(90)
        # to make y axis name horizontal 
        ax.yaxis.label.set_rotation(0)
        # to make sure y axis names are outside the plot area
        ax.yaxis.labelpad = 50
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`scatter_matrix` returns a two-dimensional array of `matplotlib` subplots.  This means you should be able to iterate over the two arrays and use `matplotlib` functions to rotate axes.  Based on the source used to implement [`scatter_matrix`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tools/plotting.py#L210) and the private helper function [`_label_axis`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tools/plotting.py#L324), it looks as though you should be able to perform your rotations for all the plots with:

```
from matplotlib.artist import setp

x_rotation = 90
y_rotation = 90

for row in axs:
    for subplot in row:
        setp(subplot.get_xticklabels(), rotation=x_rotation)
        setp(subplot.get_yticklabels(), rotation=y_rotation)
```

I don't have a good way to test this so it may require a bit of playing around.